# Makefile compilation error from cuda/cpp program

Tags: c++, makefile, cuda

This is the first time I try to create a makefile (this is for a student project).
First, I got two different source : 
- convolve.cu and main.cpp in a src folder.
One cuda header :
- convolve.cuh in an include folder.
I created a obj folder for the futur .o

Now I present a partial contents of each files :

main.cpp :

```
#include "CImg.h"
#include "../include/convolve.cuh"
using namespace cimg_library;

int main(){
CImg<float> var1("/*path*/");
CImg<float> var2("/*path2*/");
convolve(&var1,&var2);
//some code
}
```

convolve.cu :

```
#include "CImg.h"
#include "cuda.h"
using namespace cimg_library;

__constant__ filter[N][M];
__global__ void kernel(/*some arg*/){
//some code
}

__host__ void convolve(/*some arg*/){
//some code
}
```

convolve.cuh :

```
#ifndef CONVOLVE_H
#define CONVOLVE_H
#define N /*value*/
#define M /*value*/

extern __constant__ filter[N][M];
extern __host__ void convolve(CImg<float>&,const CImg<float>&);
extern __global__ void kernel(/*some arg*/);
#endif //CONVOLVE_H
```

cuda.h is not in the default path but is at the following one :
`/usr/local/cuda-9.0/include`
and needs those library : `-lX11 -lpthread -lcudart`
located there : `/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64`

By reading some lectures on the internet I got through this makefile, which I placed in my src folder next to main.cpp :

makefile :

```
1 CC=nvcc
2 IDIR =../include
3 special_IDIR = /usr/local/cuda-9.0/include
4 LDIR = /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64
5 CFLAGS=-I$(special_IDIR) -L$(LDIR)
6 
7 LIBS = -lX11 -lpthread -lcudart
8 ODIR = ../obj
9 
10 
11 _DEPS = convolve.cuh
12 DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))
13 
14 _OBJ = main.o convolve.o
15 OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))
16 
17 $(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp
18         $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
19 
20 $(ODIR)/%.o: %.cu $(DEPS)
21         $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
22 
23 all: $(OBJ)
24         $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
25 
26 
27 .PHONY: clean
28 
29 clean:
30         rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

when I call `make all` I got two different kinds of error.
One comes from how I compile the "cuda code" : `error: ‘__host__’ does not name a type` and bring the same issue for `__global__` and `__constant__` instances.
As I am using the nvcc compiler, those definition should not be known during the compilation ? There is something I must have misunderstand about how to compile cuda kernel...

The second error tell me that there is no rule for the `../obj/main.o` target and is necessary for `all`.
I didn't find the issue. From what I understand now, this rule should not be made with those following lines ? :

```
17 $(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
18         $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Thanks for your time !

**EDIT** : I think I found where does come from the first error but do not know how to correct it. 
In my `main.cpp` file I call `convolve.cuh` which contain the `__global__`, etc... things. And I compile it with `-c` option. But if I try with `-x cu` option then I got issues with some CImg declaration (var1 and var2 for the exemple) I got inside my `main.cpp`and no more issue from `__global__`, etc... things.

Comment: You can't import convolve.cuh into a vanilla C++ file. It contains CUDA syntax

Comment: Okay, that is the issue indeed... but how can I call convolve() function into main.cpp if I don't include its prototype ?

Comment: create a wrapper file (e.g. `convolve.cu`).  In the wrapper file, create a pure C/C++ function (e.g. not using `__global__` as part of the function prototype).  From within that function, make whatever CUDA calls you wish.  Publish the prototype of that wrapper function (say, in a header file `convolve.h`).  Use that wrapper function from `main.cpp`.  Include `convolve.h` in `main.cpp`.  `convolve.h` should not have any CUDA keywords in it (i.e. no `__global__`, no `__host__`)

Comment: Please don't edit questions to make them into different questions. Roll-back your edit and ask a new question with only the problem you're having right now - which seems to not have anything to do with CUDA.

Comment: okay I thunk we should do lke this ^^'